# How do I set up new users with skel

Tags: users

i have on my server a settings i use for all my users. every time i create a new user i have to copy all the settings over and over.

for example:

- .vimrc.
- .profile
- .bashrc
- firefox homepage to our intranet
- evolution settings (server and username)
  etc...

i saw skel can do it, is there a easy way to setup a user with my settings when i `adduser`?

thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Everything should be located in the `/etc/skel` folder.

You need to create a link on the desktop for all users:

```
mkdir -p /etc/skel/Desktop
cd /etc/skel/Desktop/
vi shortcut.desktop
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Name=ShortCut
    Comment=Visit ShortCut
    GenericName=ShortCut
    Exec=firefox http://intranet.ShortCut.com
    Terminal=false
    X-MultipleArgs=false
    Type=Application
    Icon=firefox
    Categories=Internet
chmod +x shortcut.desktop
```

That will create a link on the desktop.

*Here's few articles that will help you for what you need:*

- [How do I apply a custom Gnome-shell theme for all users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117566/how-do-i-apply-a-custom-gnome-shell-theme-for-all-users)
- [How to ensure that all new users have the same profile settings as the current user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186487/how-to-ensure-that-all-new-users-have-the-same-profile-settings-as-the-current-u)
- http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/using_skel.htm
- http://humanreadable.nfshost.com/sdeg/etc_skel.htm
- http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html
- http://www.booser.com/etc-skel-directory.html
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/useradd-adduser-newuser-how-to-create-linux-users/#more-552

Answer (score 1):

I think putting the various things you want to use in /etc/skel is the simplest.

The other option would be to script it.