# How do I apply a custom Gnome-shell theme for all users?

Tags: gnome, themes

I am using Gnome-shell on Ubuntu 11.10. I've found excellent theme, which I'd like to apply to all users, current and ones that are created later. Is there a way to set the new theme (Elementary Luna) as the default theme, or if not, replace the old theme completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your configuration files into `/etc/skel`.
The window theme settings are located at `/home/YourUsername/.gconf/desktop/gnome/shell/windows/%gconf.xml` so you copy the settings file to `/etc/skel/.gconf/desktop/gnome/shell/windows/%gconf.xml`.

Then you do the same for `.gconf/desktop/gnome/interface/%gconf.xml`, this is where icon theme and gtk-Theme settings are stored.

You can do so with all settings in your home folder.

Comment: The elementary luna theme is a shell theme. Your answer covers the icon theme and the gtk-theme but not the shell theme. Please update your answer to reflect that part.

Comment: I couldn't find this one but it could be that the settings are located in the shell extension directory. I'll test it soon.

Comment: gnome-tweak-tool can't start anymore after i installed the user-themes extension... Sorry but it could take a while until I find out how I can fix this and where the extension stores its settings. But you could test if it works to just put the extensions directory (~/.local/share/gnome-shell/_userthemeextension_) to /etc/skel and see if that works.