# Create global Template directory

Tags: filesystem, xdg

I want to move Template directory out from my  `~` home folder. I would like to have one global Template directory. One option, that I think can be possible is to create a link(shortcut or how is it called in linux) to Template, but then Template file would still be in my folder and I don't know where to put global Template folder, where is a place, that should be used by it (maybe `/opt`?). So basically:

- Is it possible to create one global Template folder instead of Template for every user? And how? (by one, I mean, that I'm able to remove Template folder from every user).

If not:

- Where should I put a folder with templates, where is a good place for putting my global configurations in linux?

EDIT: I checked and put my global Templates folder in /opt/Template, then I made a link from every user account to that place and it works fine, but still I have no idea, if it is possible to get rid of Template folder (or link) completely in user's home folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It is indeed possible to create a *global template* folder as the picture shows.

To do this you can edit the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Change the line `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"` to `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="/opt/Templates"` if your global folder is in `/opt/Templates`

**Note 1** - you should consider carefully the permissions you give this template folder.  I would suggest you should give read-only rights with a common group shared by those users of a client.  Obviously try to avoid `777` rights to this folder since this makes the folder read-writable to everyone and anyone.

**Note 2** - the `XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR` folder needs to be EITHER a folder locate in the users home or  an absolute folder (full path to the folder starting with `/`)

**Note 3** - you dont necessarily need to modify `user-dirs.dirs`.  You could remove the local home-folder and soft-link it to your global templates folder i.e.

```
cd ~/
rmdir Templates
ln -s /opt/Templates Templates
```

**Note 4** - logout and login for changes to take effect

Comment: great. For an opt and Templates I made 755, for files inside Templates I made 744. Everything works perfectly. Do I need to change user-dirs,dir or soft-link folder every time I create a new user? Or is there any way to automate this process?

Comment: @Benjamin - according to this Q&A - you need to put your modified `.config/user-dirs.dirs` into /etc/skel - there are some very useful links in the accepted answer as to how to customise new user accounts.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/83532/how-do-i-set-up-new-users-with-skel