# How to change Desktop default environment for new users

Tags: customization

I want to set default Desktop environment (the question is not about gnome-panel, KDE etc.), need to unlock unnecessary icons from launcher and lock needed applications on launcher, set keyboard layout 2 or 3 languages on menu bar.
And when I create new user and he/she will log in, the desktop environment will be same that I created.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/186487/how-to-ensure-that-all-new-users-have-the-same-profile-settings-as-the-current-u does this address the issue ? I didn't flag as a duplicate because it may be a bit diffrent

Answer (score 0):

After creating a user copy **.config** directory from your home directory to the home directory of a new user.

Enter Files manager with sudo priveligies.

```
 sudo nautilus
```

Then Go to **/home/user1** directory.Press Ctlr+H to see hidden files. There is a .config directory where user settings are stored.Copy it with right click menu.

Then go to **/home/user2** directory. Right click and Paste.

Now log out and enter to the new user account.

Comment: I have LDAP client installed, and need to customize new users Desktop automatically, not manually (because the users home created after log in).

Comment: Can you help me? your answer is not helped me???

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge beyond that.