# How do I set up a default profile for new users?

Tags: unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up new users with skel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83532/how-do-i-set-up-new-users-with-skel)

I am building a new PC for my fiancee's family, and want to set it up so that some setting are defaulted when a new user account for each family member is created.

The settings I'm looking to set up are:

- Background opacity of the top bar and the unity launcher
- The default icons in the unity launcher and on the desktop
- The size of the unity icons
- Default applications for music, web browser, etc.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!