# Changing wallpaper and language setting after su command?

Tags: desktop-background, language-support, su

Some time after su command I feel uncertain by seeing other wallpaper than the one corresponding to the new user. Is there any command usable at a batch, that I could use for quick switching that wallpapers?

(Original question asked also about switching languages. I have been advised by comments -thanks - and first I'll try a batch for it.)

Comment: `su` only starts a shell as another user. It does not affect your desktop session, so your wallpaper will obviously stay the same. If you want to graphically log in as another user, select the user in your system menu (cogwheel in the top right corner of your screen) or click on "switch users" there.

Comment: To change the language of a shell session, you can temporarily set the `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` and/or `LC_ALL` environment variables inside your shell session. Can't tell you what exact values are possible there though, that depends on your installed locales.

Comment: @Byte Commander: In my Ubuntu 16.04, for changing the language of the 'info' help from my Czech to US English, it is sufficient to write 'GDM_LANG=en_US' in the Terminal. I'd like to vote for your advice, but it has not the form of an answer. And I am ashamed to ask a question made from it and answer it.

Comment: Nah, if my comment pushed you in the right direction, that's fine. Feel free to describe whatever you did in a self-answer. After all, I just gave you a quick suggestion and you figured out the rest.

Comment: @Byte Commander:  Thanks, but it has shown that I cannot achieve further things I supposed to be consequences. I feel that such unsure first experimental result is not a good base (I even cannot exclude my mistake) and that I should study it much deeper before I advise others . My shyness appears to have had a reasonable basis. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 0):

For changing wallpaper at login time, you could add this command at the end of /home/$user/.profile:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///folder/file
```

For newer users, it's a good practice to customize home in */etc/skel*. Copy your modified .profile to there. See this: [How setup new users with skel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83532/how-do-i-set-up-new-users-with-skel)

Comment: Small but important correction: s/get/set/

Comment: OK @GunnarHjalmarsson, you're right. Corrected.