# '~/.bashrc' vs ' /etc/skel/.bashrc'. Why are there two '.bashrcs'?

Tags: bashrc

Why are there two .bashrcs, `~/.bashrc` and  `/etc/skel/.bashrc`?  When I compare them, I find no difference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Every file in `/etc/skel` gets copied to a (new) users $HOME directory when your create a new user. If they are the same you either have not made any changes to your file (most likely) or you copied your custom file to `/etc/skel`.

See:

[How do I set up new users with skel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83532/how-do-i-set-up-new-users-with-skel)

http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/using_skel.htm

Answer (score 11):

`/etc/skel/.bashrc` is a default `.bashrc` for every user created in the system.

`~/.bashrc` is individual for each user.